# android menu after menu

Tags: android, menu

Is there a way that when I click an option from an android menu (the ones edited in xml files) then there appears another menu?

I think there should be something out there related to this, but I did not find anything.

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#xml you simply have to add nested `<menu>` tag to your `<item>` tag.